# Using NSUserDefaults how to save a key before app is first run

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I have an app where I need a BOOL value to persist across launches.

The value should be YES on the first launch and user-customizable thereafter.

But if it's the first launch, how do I set the default to YES before the program is run?

Comment: code example here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664177/best-way-to-check-if-an-iphone-app-is-running-for-the-first-time/1664284#1664284

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to register a dictionary of default values with NSUserDefaults on every launch of your app:

```
NSDictionary *defaultValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
    [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"myUserDefaultsKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultValues];
```

Now,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"myUserDefaultsKey"];
```

will return YES if the key is not present.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to include a plist file with the default values in your app.
If the preferences are not available (first launch), then simply creates them from the default plist file...