# How can an ios app download pictures from a web service and install them at users ios device during installation?

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services, installation, image

How can an ios app download pictures from a web service and install them at users ios device during installation? Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have control over the app's installation on the user's device so it's not possible to download additional data during the installation.

Just download your pictures at the first app launch after the installation. To check if the app was launched the first time, you could either check if the pictures already exist on the device or use NSUserDefaults: [Best way to check if an iPhone app is running for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664177/best-way-to-check-if-an-iphone-app-is-running-for-the-first-time)

Hope this helps.